# Using AppleScript to find information about images in Pages documents

Tags: applescript, pages

I'm trying to extract information about images placed into a Pages ('09 v 4.3) document. The following script is my attempt:

```
tell application "Pages"
    tell front document
        repeat with pg in pages
            tell pg
                set im to images
                repeat with i in im
                    tell i
                        get image data
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

While it doesn't produce errors, and finds every image, it doesn't return any data either and I don't know why it doesn't:

```
get every image of item 1 of every page of document 1
        --> {image 1 of foreground layer of page 1 of document id 14126328}
get image data of image 1 of foreground layer of page 1 of document id 14126328
get every image of item 2 of every page of document 1
        --> {image 1 of foreground layer of page 2 of document id 14126328}
get image data of image 1 of foreground layer of page 2 of document id 14126328
get every image of item 4 of every page of document 1
    --> {image 1 of foreground layer of page 4 of document id 14126328}
get image data of image 1 of foreground layer of page 4 of document id 14126328
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work you almost got it. I would suggest looking at the properties instead of the data ;)

```
tell application "Pages"
    tell front document
        repeat with pg in pages
            tell pg
                set im to images
                repeat with i in im
                    tell i
                        get properties
                    end tell
                end repeat
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks! (+1) With AppleScript you never know how close you are... :) Do you happen to know how to get the image's filename - there's no `image data` property in the listing of this script, although it's in the dictionary?